# Change hover name footer section shopify

Tags: shopify

How can I have change the name of the social links in the footer section. I changed tumblr icon to a different icon but when hovered, it still shows tumblr name. How can I changed it? I am using Narrative Theme.

Please help.

Comment: update the title tag to update the hover text.

Comment: that worked. How can I also customize the icon image?

Comment: You need to check the code into the header or footer according to your time and need to edit the code according to your needs.